# Why is my phone vibrating incessantly during calls?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, calls, vibration, htc-thunderbolt

Yesterday, my phone started vibrating once every 15 seconds or so during phone calls. I'm running cyanogenmd 7 on HTC thunderbolt. I looked in settings and there is only option to vibrate every 45 seconds during outgoing calls and it is off. How can I get back the old behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a similar problem, for me I had to go into the "profile" i was using "default, silent, work, ect.", and change the phone setting for vibrate to off.